# ViewModels and KnockoutJS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

I am building an ASP.NET MVC application which takes advantage of ViewModels using AutoMapper. However, I was thinking of using KnockoutJS for 'AJAX heavy' pages but that means I would also have to create ViewModels for KnockoutJS.

The major downside I can think of having two separate ViewModels is maintainability. Is there a better solution than creating two ViewModels? Also, reading a few other posts this means that the client-side ViewModel will have to be aware of the server-side which is bad practice and tightly couples the two together.

I must admit I haven't really used KnockoutJS in the past, but have read/gone through a few tutorials so I am a bit agnostic on this matter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think your current ViewModels can't work with KnockoutJS?

Comment: I thought that I had to create both a ViewModel for ASP.NET MVC but also one in JS for KnockoutJS? But as @twoflower suggested below I can remove this duplicity.

Comment: You actually most often do not need MVC view models when working with KO, you can use the Domain entities straight off

Comment: I completely agree with that @Anders but then that introduces the problem that same Controllers work with KO and some dont. I dont wanna fully KOify my WebApp, but only the AJAX heavy pages, hence why I wanted to keep everything consistent.

I.e Have an ASP.NET Model which 'maps' to KO ViewModel and then do what I need with KO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duplicity can be to a great extent reduced by the following approach:

```
@model ViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewModel(initData) {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(initData, {}, self);

        // Add custom view model logic
        ...

        // Logic for persisting the current state of the model back to the server
        self.Save = function() {                
            $.ajax('/model-uri', {
              type: 'POST',
              contentType: "application/json",
              data: ko.toJSON(self)                  
         });
    };

    var initialData = @(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
    var model = new ViewModel(initialData);
    ko.applyBindings(model);
</script>
```

Note that we're serializing the server-provided view model to a JavaScript object and then making its properties observable using the [`ko.mapping`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Knockout.Mapping) plugin which saves us duplicating the view model definition on the client side. We also employ the `ko.toJSON` utility function when sending the updated model back to the server.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll give it a shot as soon as I go home. However, what happens with the Data Attributes & Validations of the ASP.NET ViewModels?

Comment: The server-side validation will work, provided you receive the client-sent data as your server-side ViewModel object.

Comment: I presume though that client-side validation won't work when using KO so I will have to implement that in the custom view model logic? Maybe use a framework such as Knockout Validation?

If I got this correct it would looking something like:
    //Add custom view model logic:

    personName: ko.observable(initData.PersonName).extend({ required: true });

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you have to supply the client-side validation logic. I am not familiar with Knockout Validation, though.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed I was missing a very important bit in my answer - using `ko.mapping.fromJS` to actually make the properties of the model observable.